# Не удается обновить view через angularjs promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mvc, promise, scope

Есть angularjs сервис, который выполняет POST http запрос и возвращает ответ:

```
 app.service('loginservice', function ($http) {

    this.login = function (userlogin) {
        var parameter = JSON.stringify({ Email: userlogin.username, Password: userlogin.password });

            var resp = $http({
                url: "http://localhost:62366/api/account/login",
                method: "POST",
                data: parameter,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            });



        return resp;
    };
});
```

Полный текст Script'a, который выполняется при нажатии кнопочки login на одной страничке и должен переходить на другую:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('app');
    app.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, loginservice, ) {

        //Scope Declaration
        $scope.responseData = "";

        $scope.user = "";

        $scope.userRegistrationEmail = "";
        $scope.userRegistrationPassword = "";
        $scope.userRegistrationConfirmPassword = "";

        $scope.userLoginEmail = "";
        $scope.userLoginPassword = "";

        $scope.accessToken = "";
        $scope.refreshToken = "";
        //Ends Here


        //Function to Login. This will generate Token 

        $scope.justlogin = function () {


            //This is the information to pass for token based authentication
            var userLogin = {
                grant_type: 'password',
                username: $scope.userLoginEmail,
                password: $scope.userLoginPassword
            };

            var promiselogin = loginservice.login(userLogin);

                promiselogin.then(function (resp) {


                    //Store the token information in the SessionStorage
                    //So that it can be accessed for other views
                    sessionStorage.setItem('userName', resp.data.role);
                    sessionStorage.setItem('accessToken', resp.data.id_token);
                    sessionStorage.setItem('refreshToken', resp.data.refresh_token);

                    $scope.user = resp.data.role;
                    console.log($scope.user);
                    window.location.href = '/#/profile';



                }, function (err) {

                    $scope.responseData = "Error " + err.status;

                });


        };


    });

    var app = angular.module('app');

    app.service('loginservice', function ($http) {


        this.login = function (userlogin) {
            var parameter = JSON.stringify({ Email: userlogin.username, Password: userlogin.password });

                var resp = $http({
                    url: "http://localhost:62366/api/account/login",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: parameter,
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
                });



            return resp;
        };
    });
}())
```

Вобщем-то всё прекрасно биндится и работает, но вот соответствующая $scope.user свойству переменная во вью остается неизменной, хотя в консоль лог отображает необходимые изменения.

HTML страничка:

```
<div class="row wrapper border-bottom white-bg page-heading">
<div class="col-lg-10" ng-controller="LoginController">
    <h2>{{user}}</h2>
```

Уже не один день ломаю голову над данным вопросом и был бы очень признателен, если кто-нибудь поможет разрешить такую головоломку...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47313/discussion-on-question-by-----view--angularjs-promis).

Comment: Нашел удовлетворительный "костыль". Просты вытягиваю нужный мне параметр из sessionStorage и присваиваю нужному свойству:
`setTimeout(function () {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                $scope.user = sessionStorage.getItem('userName');
            });
        }, 2000);`

Answer (score 0):

Можно вызвать $scope.$apply() после обновления $scope.user